# suddenly My android Button on click is not working in most of the screens

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some buttons on my android app which I am developing and suddenly some of the button click is not working. 
Here is the code for my button  click.

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {      
                    myIntent=new Intent(relationship.this, relationship.class);

                    String uname;
                    uname=myValues.getString("value").toString();

                    myIntent.putExtra("value", uname);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }

            });
```

And I have also tried different ways changed to **view.onclicklistener**  But is no use the following error I am getting.

```
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newairways/com.example.newairways.relationship}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.example.newairways.relationship.onCreate(relationship.java:81)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-24 08:17:03.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;



public class relationship extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    //Variables Assign
    private SeekBar mSeekBar1, mSeekBar2;
    private TextView tv1, tv2;
    private Button ok,nextQ,cancel;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    Intent myIntent;
    Bundle myValues;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relationships);
        myValues=getIntent().getExtras();
        mSeekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Q1a); 
        mSeekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mSeekBar2= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Q1b); 
        mSeekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);


        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ans1a);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ans1b);

        //Userame Assign
       TextView welcomeMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
        welcomeMsg.setText("name : "+myValues.getString("value"));

           ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
            nextQ = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextquestion);
            cancel= (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    //Storing in Global variables
                    String a = tv1.getText().toString();
                    String Q1b = tv2.getText().toString();
                    GlobalVars.setSeekBarValue(a);
                    GlobalVars.setSeekBarValue1b(Q1b);
                    Toast.makeText(relationship.this, "Datastored",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }

           });     


            nextQ.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {      
                    myIntent=new Intent(relationship.this, start.class);

                    String uname;
                    uname=myValues.getString("value").toString();

                    myIntent.putExtra("value", uname);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }

            }); 

            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {      
                    myIntent=new Intent(relationship.this, relationship.class);

                    String uname;
                    uname=myValues.getString("value").toString();

                    myIntent.putExtra("value", uname);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }

            }); 




    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        switch (seekBar.getId())
        {

        case R.id.Q1a:

            tv1.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%") ;
            //Toast.makeText(relationship.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

case R.id.Q1b:
    tv2.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%") ;
            //Toast.makeText(relationship.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        } 
    }






    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you initialize the `Button`?  `Button cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID);`

Comment: Are you trying to restart the same activity? Seeing as you're starting `relationship.class` from `relationship.this`.

Comment: yes I am trying to restart the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have NPE in your relationship activity. I bet that myValues.getString("value") returns null, that is then passed as "value" extra.

Comment: Look at the stacktrace. The nullpointerexception is being thrown in the `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity` method. I doubt it has anything to do with the string, it is more likely to be about the intent.

Comment: I have tried the intent but I dont any problem with intend. because it worked for me before but suddenly started to show error.

Answer (score 1):

**NullPointerException** is at:

`Relationship.java` - **Line 81**

Check this line in the class and there you are getting null value on assign.

Comment: No I was not getting null value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the local variable then first initialize that one

```
String uname=null;
 uname=myValues.getString("value").toString();
```

And second this you are starting the same activity class that meaningless.
And third thing to check the uname value when you get it does have `null` or not

Comment: Hi I have tried like you advised but it doesn't work still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Share your relationship.java file code with the line no 81 as highlighted.
I hope you haven't forgot to mention this activity in the manifest file.

Comment: Hi I have have it running before but suddenly it is showing error at this point.

Comment: Please share your complete file. From this code, I am not able to get that which line is line no. 81. Error may be because of some other reason.

Comment: I have upload my code..please let me know where the problem is.

Comment: sometime myValues.getString("value") may be returning null and you are trying to pass that to toString function           cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {      
                    myIntent=new Intent(relationship.this, relationship.class);

                    String uname;
                    uname=myValues.getString("value");
                    if(name!=null)
                       myIntent.putExtra("value", uname);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }

            });

Comment: By the way why are you calling Relationship activity again. you can simply write return; and you will remain on same activity with same value of userName. You haven't changed anything in bundle. So there isn't any purpose of calling it again with same parameter. And as I said in previous comment change myValues.getString("value").toString(); to myValues.getString("value");